# Basic set theory proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove $(A \times B = B \times A) \Leftrightarrow  (A = \varnothing \ or \ B = \varnothing \ or \ B = A)$ ?

I'm not sure about my solution.

Comment: I'm not sure about my solution but now everything is clear.

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

If $\;A,B\neq\emptyset\;$:

$$A\times B=B\times A\iff \forall \;a\in A\;,\;b\in B\;,\;\;(a,b)\in B\times A\iff a\in B\;\wedge\;b\in A$$

Answer (score 1):

First, suppose $A$ or $B$ is $\emptyset$- then both $A\times B=\emptyset=B\times A$. Suppose then that $A,B\neq\emptyset$. If we have that $A\times B =B\times A$, then any element $(a,b)$ of $A\times B$ has a corresponding element in $B\times A$, thus if $a\in A$, then $a\in B$, and likewise if $b\in B$, then $b\in A$, thus $A\subset B$, $B\subset A$, and thus $B=A$.